# ADB Device Cannot be Authorized in User build

Tags: android, adb, android-source

I am making user-build with the Android Open Source Project. I want to authorize ADB using the **adbkey.pub** file that we have in the directory: **~/.android**.

For this, I put this file in a suitable place in our path (~AOSP_Source/android/device/XX/YY) And the following command has been added to the .mk file as shown below:

---

ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),user)

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += device/XX/YY/adbkey.pub:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_DATA)/misc/adb/adb_keys

endif

---

After the compilation is completed, it is observed that the **adbkey.pub** file is in the correct directory under the 'out' folder and it is the same content as  the **~/.android/adbkey.pub**

In addition to these, we are working with the following configuration.
**androidboot.selinux=permissive**

When I plug in the device using USB, it is not automatically authorized.

How can we authorized automatically for ADB device?

Answer (score 0):

Set the PRODUCT_ADB_KEYS, check https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/0bd793815e8c1d7830c6753e399b70d4bfb4a88b%5E%21/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in your device's product.mk:

```
#Sets the ADB security always ON
#This means that the ADB sessions needs the device keys to work
PRODUCT_DEFAULT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES+= \
    ro.adb.secure=1

#Add the adb keys
#The private pair needs to be known by the client which needs to access the device
PRODUCT_ADB_KEYS := device/XX/YY/keys/adbkey.pub
```

device/XX/YY/keys/adbkey.pub should be the path where your keys are stored